# How to upload software written in Gambas into a Launchpad PPA?

Tags: ppa, launchpad

I have a software written in Gambas 3, which I need a PPA to store it. I've heard that Launchpad builds packages by the source, and does not accept user built deb packages. Does Launchpad have a Gambas 3 compiler, to compile my source package? If not, how can I host my Gambas based software in Launchpad?
Thanks!

Note: I have already made a PPA & signed the code of conduct.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK launchpad doesn't support a Gambas compiler/build system out of the box, but you could have the package that provides the compiler in your build-depends to make sure it's present in the build environment.